# JS Show not uploaded image

Tags: javascript, image, upload

I'd like to make an upload form (for images) which will show selected images. Is that possible to do that without uploading images on a server? Or I should firstly upload images, get links, and only after that show images?

Answer (score 0):

You can not show the image until you uplaod it on server barbecue **you can not access anything of clients machine** some exception(cookies etc which are well knows)

Comment: Thanks, but how should I upload that? I wrote a script on php which gets an image, uploads that and gives the link. Should I send links with form? But I will be need to check that. Or there is a better way?